How to Convert <T> to bytes[] and retrieve back from bytes[] in UWP application
Can someone please help me to convert all properties of PacketData object to byte[] and retrieve it back from byte[] to a PacketData object again?
I'm using this object to send through socket data from one page to another in an UWP application...
Code snippet:
class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class PacketData<T>
{
    // Default constructor
    public PacketData()
    {
        this.cmdCommand = Command.Null;
        this.StringData = null;
        this.strName = null;
        this.Data = null;
    }

    // Converts the bytes into an object of type Data
    public PacketData(byte[] data)
    {
        //The first four bytes are for the Command
        this.cmdCommand = (Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

        //The next four store the length of the name
        int nameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);

        //The next four store the length of the message
        int msgLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 8);

        //This check makes sure that strName has been passed in the array of bytes
        if (nameLen > 0)
            this.strName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12, nameLen);
        else
            this.strName = null;

        //This checks for a null message field
        if (msgLen > 0)
            this.StringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 12 + nameLen, msgLen);
        else
            this.StringData = null;
    }

    //Converts the Data structure into an array of bytes
    public byte[] ToByte()
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        //First four are for the Command
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cmdCommand));

        //Add the length of the name
        if (strName != null)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(strName.Length));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        //Length of the message
        if (StringData != null)
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(StringData.Length));
        else
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

        //Add the name
        if (strName != null)
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strName));

        //And, lastly we add the message text to our array of bytes
        if (StringData != null)
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringData));

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public string strName;      //Name by which the client logs into the room
    public string StringData;   //Message text
    public Command cmdCommand;  //Command type (login, logout, send message, etcetera)

    public T Data;  //generic type (object/ list/ int/ string)
}

enum Command
{
    Login,      //Log into the server
    Logout,     //Logout of the server
    Message,    //Send a text message to all the chat clients
    List,       //Get a list of users in the chat room from the server
    Null
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];

    byte[] message; = new PacketData(byteData);

    #region Data object to send data 
    var school = new School { Id = 1, Name = "Test Name" };

    var packetData = new PacketData<School>
    {
        cmdCommand = Command.Login,
        strName = "Login Data",
        Data = school,
        StringData = null
    }; 
    #endregion

    //Convert all properties into bytes
    message = packetData.ToByte();

    //retirve all properties from bytes
    PacketData msgReceived = new PacketData(message);
}

I'm expecting to send any type of data in <T> Data properties through socket..also retrieve it back

Depends on how you handle your data. If you use JSON serialization and then send it as bytes, you could use somehting like: JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));

"I'm expecting to send any type of data in <T> Data ". You won't be able to send any kind of data. For example, you won't be able to send an open FileStream.

Use a serializer. I suggest MessagePack because it is very fast.
https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp
It supports both typed and untyped serialization. You probably want to use typed serialization for your purposes
Data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(data);

or
Data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize<T>(data);


Alternatively there's also MemoryPack by the same author as MessagePack (it's somewhat faster but can't be used for some cases).
